# Xamarin.Android Facebook Native Login

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I had a Xamarin.Android app FB native login working few days back but now it's all broke. It works smooth on Genymotion but on devices, it takes so much time to show Facebook app authentication and worst of all, when it comes back, nothing happens. Page is still as it was before clicking on FB button.
Below is the code snippet:

Initialization:

[assembly: MetaData ("com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId", Value = "@string/app_id")]

[assembly: MetaData ("com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName", Value = "@string/app_name")]

internal TaskCompletionSource FacebookLoginTask = new TaskCompletionSource ();

Then in Oncreate:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        #region Fb Native Login
        FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (this.ApplicationContext);
        callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create ();

        FacebookLoginTask = new TaskCompletionSource<string> ();

        var loginCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            HandleSuccess = loginResult => FacebookLoginTask.SetResult (loginResult.AccessToken.Token),
            HandleCancel = FacebookLoginTask.SetCanceled,
            HandleError = FacebookLoginTask.SetException
        };

        LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback (callbackManager, loginCallback);
        #endregion

        InitializeComponents ();
    }
```

On FB Button Click:

```
private async void btnFB_Onclick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO : Set permission in global values
        if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.Token)) {
            //LoginManager.Instance.LogOut ();
            LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions (this, new string[] {
                "user_birthday",
                "read_stream",
                "email",
                "user_location"
            });
            await GetAccessToken ();
        } else {
            LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions (this, new string[] {
                "user_birthday",
                "read_stream",
                "email",
                "user_location"
            });
            await GetAccessToken ();
        }
```

And finally:

```
async Task GetAccessToken ()
    {
        try {
            IsContainEmail = true;
            string accessToken = string.Empty;
            if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.Token))
                accessToken = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.Token;
            else {
                if (!ControllerHelper.IsOnline (this))
                    return;
                ActivityView = ProgressDialog.Show (this, "Please wait", "Authenticating...", true);
                accessToken = await FacebookLoginTask.Task;
//It does not fallback here
                Console.WriteLine (accessToken);
                try {
                    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient (accessToken);
                    var me = await fb.GetTaskAsync ("me");
                    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)me;
                    Console.WriteLine (result.ToString ());
                    if (!result.ContainsKey ("email") || string.IsNullOrEmpty ((string)result ["email"])) {
                        IsContainEmail = false;
                    }
                    if (IsContainEmail) {
                        await CreateFBRegistration (result);
                    }
                    ActivityView.Dismiss ();
                    ActivityView.Dispose ();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    IsContainEmail = false;
                    Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
                    ActivityView.Dismiss ();
                    ActivityView.Dispose ();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ActivityView.Dismiss ();
            ActivityView.Dispose ();
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It got stuck at await FacebookLoginTask.Task; Although I got callback hit:

```
//Must include to trigger the callback
    protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.OnActivityResult (requestCode, (int)resultCode, data);
    }
```

Don't know whats wrong. It was working few days back. Any suggestions??

Comment: Actually, it's working again but only in debug mode. In release mode, getting Invalid key hash. xxxx does not match any stored key hashes.

Comment: I would delete this question if this is no longer relevant.

Comment: I resolved the issue by creating release hash key.